# Model View Controller inheritance

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have these folder structure:
[image: https://image.ibb.co/eB6UXm/ordner.png]

The Application.php looks so:

```
<?php
namespace Mensa;
class Application extends \Application\Application{
public function getLayoutViewScript()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../view/index.php';
}
}
```

My problem is that I want to extend a class in my Application Class in the Mensa Namespace. The class I want to extend is located in Application/Applivation.php (has the same name).

But when I run I get the errot "Fatal error: Class 'Application\Application' not found..."

So how can I inherit the class in Application folder?

Thx!

Comment: Should be `class Application extends \Application\Application{` notice the \

Comment: the error changed from "Fatal error: Class 'Mensa\Application\Application' not found" into "Fatal error: Class 'Application\Application' not found"

Comment: Then its not being autoloaded. Your using an autoloader right?

Comment: No I use require_once

Comment: I don't use an autoloader

Comment: So you should. Personally I recommend you start using composer. It is not only a wonderful deps manager but also provides easy autoloading.

Comment: That will only work if your calling it, meaning every class you intend to use should be bootstrapped first. can you check that the Application/Application.php class is in the namespace Application;

Comment: These are the first lines of Application/Application.php: <?php
namespace Application;

require_once(__DIR__.'/Page/PageInterface.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/Renderer.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/NavigationItem.php');

use Application\Page\PageInterface;

class Application{ ... }

Comment: Looks ok so you must not be bootstrapping/requiring `\Application\Application` for `\Mensa\Application` to use, the whole `require_once` approach should be switched out for an autoloader it will become unmaintainable/confusing/difficult to refactor pretty fast as your already seeing. Even if just a basic `spl_autoload'er` or composers.